# android inputType=number only integer values

Tags: android, integer, android-edittext

I have an edit text with the attribute `android:inputType="number"`. The problem is that I only want the edit text to show integer numbers but it allways display with 1 decimal place. ex( I want to show 1 and it shows 1.0). I have tried all the other number related input types and its the same.

This should be a pretty basic question. What I am missing here?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: uh, inputType is related to the softkey options and what input it accepts. I don't think it has anything to do with the display of edittext.getText() ... Although, you might wanna use an `OnEditorActionListener`

Answer (score 0):

try to use :

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```